# JSON values in php foreach gives incorrect json encoded output

Tags: php, json

I have ajax url php code as follows:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["icdmaincode"]) && !empty($_POST["icdmaincode"])) 
{
    $icd_main_code = strip_tags(trim($_POST["icdmaincode"]));
}
$stmt5 = $conn->prepare("SELECT icd_sub_code,icd_sub_code_description 
                        FROM icd_sub_code 
                        WHERE icd_main_code = :icdmaincode");
$stmt5->bindValue(':icdmaincode', $icd_main_code);
$stmt5->execute();
$row = $stmt5->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($row as $key => $value)
{
    echo json_encode(array($key => $value));
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

and it is giving output as follows which is **not valid json**.

```
[{"icd_sub_code":"icdcat1-1","icd_sub_code_description":"(A00-A09) Intestinal infectious diseases"}]
{"1":{"icd_sub_code":"icdcat1-2","icd_sub_code_description":"(A15-A19) Tuberculosis"}}
{"2":{"icd_sub_code":"icdcat1-3","icd_sub_code_description":"(A20-A28) Certain zoonotic bacterial diseases"}}
```

and hence the following ajax success code is not working:

```
success: function(data){
    var subcode = data.icd_sub_code;
    var subcodedescription = data.icd_sub_code_description;
    subcode = JSON.parse(subcode);  
    alert(subcode); 
    .....
```

What am i doing wrong ?? How can i resolve it ??

Comment: You are returning an JSON array of objects. So your javascript needs to process `data` as an array. Assuming you have taken @AbraCadaver advice on the PHP Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would build an array, encode and then display:

```
foreach($row as $key => $value)
{
    $data[] = array($key => $value);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

But you actually have it all already in that type of array, so no need to loop:

```
echo json_encode($row);
```

Also, just FYI `empty` checks `isset` so just:

```
if (!empty($_POST["icdmaincode"]))
```

Comment: You might want to also add some array processing into the javascript code

Comment: @AbraCadaver oops..I overlooked the fact that $row was an array. Newbie programmer oversight. Thank you very much :)